# Executing node script from php web application (Windows)

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, exec

I have a php web application and on one of the route I try to execute node script.

Node script location: `C:\Users\meusr\Workspace\www\myproject\directImport.js`

I have configured my package.json, such that npm start executes above script.

php (laravel) application's executable index.php located at: `C:\Users\meusr\Workspace\www\myPHPproject\public\`

And on one of my route: importer/run

I have:

```
$commandToRun = "npm start --prefix ". env('IMPORTER_PATH'). " /dev/null 2>&1";
```

Where IMPORTER_PATH is configured in my env, as: IMPORTER_PATH = `C:\Users\meusr\Workspace\www\myproject\`

when I try to execute the command with `exec`

```
exec($commandToRun, $output);
```

Page keeps on loading no output, no error and no end.

The script has no issue and running the same command on command line on windows system works:

```
npm start --prefix C:\Users\meusr\Workspace\www\myproject\
```

outputs as expected.

I thought it was issue with permission first (which should have thrown error, but I still tried and ran another command)

`exec('npm -v', $output);`

which outputs my npm version.

Similarly I tried to use simply `node directImport.js` which didn't work either.

Then tried to change directory to the location where node file is located and ran the command again. 
`exec(cd C:\Users\meusr\Workspace\www\myproject\ && dir /dev/null 2>&1) // this works, but:`

`exec(cd C:\Users\meusr\Workspace\www\myproject\ && node directImport.js /dev/null 2>&1) // this didn't work`

Comment: Use the full path to `npm`

Comment: It might be worth having a look at: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html

Comment: @miken32 tried it already, but since npm or node works wouldn't that imply it is not due to path?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Still could be a missing path for something within the `npm` script though; [I had this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45763531/cant-run-node-from-web-server) and ended up being able to fix it by setting PATH through my web server.

Comment: If you can't change your server environment, you can use `proc_open` to run an external process and pass it environment variables. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53510022/1255289) for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to miken32, what worked for me was:

```
<?php 
$commandString = 'start /b c:\\programToRun.exe -attachment "c:\\temp\file1.txt"'; 
pclose(popen($commandString, 'r')); 
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php#92413